# Generate verbose names from CamelCase

Tags: python, string, camelcasing

I'm trying to obtain verbose names from CamelCase strings in Python but have no idea how to approach the problem.

This is the usecase:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def verbose_name(self, camelcase):
        return "my class"
        # ^-- here I need a way to calculate the
        #     value using the camelcase argument

    def __str__(self):
        return self.verbose_name(self.__class__.__name__)
```

I tried to implement a solution where the chunks `my` and `class` are generated detecting transitions from lower to uppercase letters, but it's very procedural, doesn't work and it's becoming too complex for such a simple task.

Any suggestion for a simple implementation to solve the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you want to split a camel case string on the Case boundary. Regex can be quite handy here

Try the following implementation

```
>>> ' '.join(re.findall("([A-Z][^A-Z]*)","MyClass")).strip()
'My Class'
```

The above implementation would fail if the name is non CamelCase conforming. In such cases, make the `caps` optional

```
>>> test_case = ["MyClass","My","myclass","my_class","My_Class","myClass"]
>>> [' '.join(re.findall("([A-Z]?[^A-Z]*)",e)) for e in test_case]
['My Class ', 'My ', 'myclass ', 'my_class ', 'My_ Class ', 'my Class ']
```

Comment: Argv!  findall!... I was attempting some strange form of `re.split` splitting on `\B` with a lookahead assertion that the next thing is a capital letter ... This is much nicer.

Answer (score 2):

Building on Abhijit's answer

```
def verbose_name(self, camelcase):
    return '_'.join(re.findall("([A-Z][^A-Z]*)", camelcase)).lower()
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
def verbose_name(self, camelcase)
    return re.sub(r'([a-z])([A-Z])',r'\1 \2', camelcase).lower()
```